# trying to get online members list in a embed in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots, embed

how i can get online members list in a embed in discord.py?
i tried but it shows only one member at time:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def sendmessage():
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for members in guild.members:
            if members.status != discord.Status.offline:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="who is online ?" , description="" , color=0x00ff00)
                embed.add_field(name="server :" , value=guild.name)
                embed.add_field(name="online :" , value=members.name)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

get all the online members in a embed

Answer (score 0):

You're currently looping over them and creating + sending a separate embed for every member.

```py
for member in guild.members:
    embed = Embed(...)
    ...
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Instead, create a list in the loop, join it to a string, and send it **once** *below* the loop.